# Template does not exist for django authentication views

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

Django newbie here. I am just trying to make a password change form using Django authentication system. I used my own views for login and logout functionality. I read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views)
and for password change form as mentioned, I made a registration folder inside my templates directory and made a template html file named `password_change_form.html` , but when I go to the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/password_change` , I keep getting the error `TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/` . Here is my app structure:

[image]

and my urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import auth
from django.urls import path,include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home_page,name='home_page'),
    path('register',views.registration_view,name='registration_view'),
    path('login',views.login_view,name='login_view'),
    path('logout',views.logout_view,name='logout_view'),
    path('accounts/password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
]
```

What and why is this happening? Please help. I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended that you view your **django.contrib.auth** files to find out more easily. Django default template for resetting the password is `templates/registration/password_reset_form.html`. As a result, your filename should be `password_reset_form.html`. For an easier understanding of this, as I mentioned, you can look at the **django.contrib.auth** files.

This urls.py file is the main django admin system:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),

    path('password_change/', views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
    path('password_change/done/', views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),

    path('password_reset/', views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

Because the views of the Django registration system are written in Class Based format, you need to put them in **.as_view()** format.
You can copy all urls related to password reset from here and put it in your **urls.py** and continue personalization.

Comment: I have edited my question for the new urls.py file and now when I go to the same link, I get the error `Page not found(404)` Also, how is the default template for resetting `password_reset_form.html`? The docs say it is `password_change_form.html`

Comment: Before putting the above comment , I should have asked where can I find the **django.contrib.auth** files?

Comment: @nmnsharma007 - As the name implies, these two templates are generally used separately! password_reset_form is the page where the user requests a password reset and password_change_form is the page where the user enters the new password. You can also access **django.contrib.auth** at ``PythonFolder/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/auth``, or if you are using virtualenv, enter the virtualenv folder instead of PythonFolder and continue on the same path.

Comment: Thanks . I found the files and understood the difference between change and reset :) Now , I am facing the problem that when I go to the password reset link, the template that opens up is by django admin and not the template that I made. What else could I be doing wrong? I have changed the html file name to `password_reset_form.html`

Comment: Ah, never mind. I got the fix here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59039168/django-2-2-instead-of-my-template-django-uses-the-standard?rq=1 Thanks for the help :D